# Recursive tree-like table query with Slick

Tags: scala, slick

My table data forms a tree structure where one row can reference a parent row in the same table.

What I am trying to achieve, using Slick, is to write a query that will return a row and all it's children. Also, I would like to do the same, but write a query that will return a child and all it's ancestors.

In other words:

`findDown(1)` should return

```
List(Group(1, 0, "1"), Group(3, 1, "3 (Child of 1)"))
```

`findUp(5)` should return

```
List(Group(5, 2, "5 (Child of 2)"), Group(2, 0, "2"))
```

Here is a fully functional worksheet (except for the missing solutions ;-).

```
package com.exp.worksheets

import scala.slick.driver.H2Driver.simple._

object ParentChildTreeLookup {

  implicit val session = Database.forURL("jdbc:h2:mem:test1;", driver = "org.h2.Driver").createSession()

  session.withTransaction {
    Groups.ddl.create
  }

  Groups.insertAll(
    Group(1, 0, "1"),
    Group(2, 0, "2"),
    Group(3, 1, "3 (Child of 1)"),
    Group(4, 3, "4 (Child of 3)"),
    Group(5, 2, "5 (Child of 2)"),
    Group(6, 2, "6 (Child of 2)"))

  case class Group(
    id: Long = -1,
    id_parent: Long = -1,
    label: String = "")

  object Groups extends Table[Group]("GROUPS") {
    def id = column[Long]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
    def id_parent = column[Long]("ID_PARENT")
    def label = column[String]("LABEL")
    def * = id ~ id_parent ~ label <> (Group, Group.unapply _)
    def autoInc = id_parent ~ label returning id into {
      case ((_, _), id) => id
    }

    def findDown(groupId: Long)(implicit session: Session) = { ??? }

    def findUp(groupId: Long)(implicit session: Session) = { ??? }
  }

}
```

A really bad, and static attempt at `findDown` may be something like:

```
private def groupsById = for {
  group_id <- Parameters[Long]
  g <- Groups; if g.id === group_id
} yield g

private def childrenByParentId = for {
  parent_id <- Parameters[Long]
  g <- Groups; if g.id_parent === parent_id
} yield g


def findDown(groupId: Long)(implicit session: Session) = { groupsById(groupId).list union childrenByParentId(groupId).list }
```

But, I'm looking for a way for Slick to recursively search the same table using the id and id_parent link. Any other good ways to solve the problem is really welcome. Keep in mind though, that it would be best to minimise the number of database round-trips.

Comment: How would you do that in SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You could try calling SQL from slick. The SQL call to go **up** the hierarchy would look something like this (This is for SQL Server):

```
WITH org_name AS 
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        parent.id AS parent_id,
        parentname.label as parent_label,
        child.id AS child_id,
        childname.ConceptName as child_label
    FROM
        Group parent RIGHT OUTER JOIN 
        Group child ON child.parent_id = parent.id
), 
jn AS 
(   
    SELECT
        parent_id,
        parent_label,
        child_id,
        child_label
    FROM
        org_name 
    WHERE
        parent_id = 5
    UNION ALL 
        SELECT
            C.parent_id,
            C.parent_label,
            C.child_id,
            C.child_label 
        FROM
            jn AS p JOIN 
            org_name AS C ON C.child_id = p.parent_id
) 
SELECT DISTINCT
    jn.parent_id,
    jn.parent_label,
    jn.child_id,
    jn.child_label
FROM
    jn 
ORDER BY
    1;
```

If you want to go down the hierarchy change the line:

```
org_name AS C ON C.child_id = p.parent_id
```

to

```
org_name AS C ON C.parent_id = p.child_id
```

Answer (score -1):

In plain SQL this would be tricky. You would have multiple options:

1. Use a stored procedure to collect the correct records (recursively). Then convert those records into a tree using code
2. Select all the records and convert those into a tree using code
3. Use more advanced technique as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4155/Improve-hierarchy-performance-using-nested-sets) (from [Optimized SQL for tree structures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/317322/optimized-sql-for-tree-structures)) and [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). Then convert those records into a tree using code

Depending on the way you want to do it in SQL you need to build a Slick query. The concept of [Leaky Abstractions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883006/meaning-of-leaky-abstraction) is very evident here.

So getting the tree structure requires two steps:

1. Get the correct (or all records)
2. Build (using regular code) a tree from those records

Since you are using Slick I don't think it's an option, but another database type might be a better fit for your data model. Check out [NoSQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoSQL) for the differences between the different types.

Comment: Thank you. In the past I've done this type of thing using stored procedures on the database side, but the depth of my trees here will typically be shallow, although the record-set may become quite large. You are probably correct in guessing that it will end in being a code-side solution, and NoSQL is not an option for this project. I was just hoping Slick users has found an optimal way or good pattern for solving this problem in a way that fits in well with other Slick queries (considering composability etc.)

Comment: Recursive SQL / hierarchical queries aren't something that SQL databases are incapable of doing. H2 for instance supports the SQL standard with its recursive CTEs, so the question is really about how to express a recursive CTE in Slick.

Comment: Here's the [relevant H2 documentation section](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#recursive_queries)

Comment: Thanks Lukas - CTE seems to be the way to go and it's also supported in PosgreSQL http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html. So great, thanks. I'll give it a go.