# How to make EF eager load a collection navigation property through a GroupJoin?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, entity-framework

I am trying to `GroupJoin` some data with an `IQueryable` and project that data into an anonymous type.  The original entity that I am `GroupJoin`ing onto has an `ICollection` navigation property (ie. one:many).  I want to eager load that property so I can access it after the group join without EF going back to the DB.  I know that `Include()` doesn't work when you use a `GroupJoin`, but the following code is the only way I have found to make it eager load the collection (`ContactRoomRoles`):

```
using (var context = new MyDbContext()) {
    var foundRooms = context.Rooms.Include(rm => rm.ContactRoomRoles);
    foundRooms.ToList();  // <-- Required to make EF actually load ContactRoomRoles data!

    var roomsData = foundRooms
        .GroupJoin(
            context.Contacts,
            rm => rm.CreatedBy,
            cont => cont.Id,
            (rm, createdBy) => new {
                ContactRoomRoles = rm.ContactRoomRoles,
                Room = rm,
                CreatedBy = createdBy.FirstOrDefault()
            }
        )
        .ToList();

    var numberOfRoles1 = roomsData.ElementAt(1).Room.ContactRoomRoles.Count();
    var numberOfRoles2 = roomsData.ElementAt(2).Room.ContactRoomRoles.Count();
    var numberOfRoles3 = roomsData.ElementAt(3).Room.ContactRoomRoles.Count();
}
```

If I remove the `foundRooms.ToList()`, EF goes off to the database 3 times to populate my `numberOfRoles` variables at the end, but with `foundRooms.ToList()` it doesn't - it just eager loads the data in one query upfront.

Although this works, it feels like a total hack.  I'm just calling `.ToList()` for the side-effect of making EF actually load the collection data.  If I comment that line out, it goes to the database any time I try to access `ContactRoomRoles`.  Is there a less hacky way to make EF eager load that navigation property?

NOTE: I want to use the navigation property rather than projecting it into a new property of the anonymous type because AutoMapper wants to access `Room.ContactRoomRoles` when it's mapping onto a DTO object.

Comment: I think it’s kind of funny that you’d use an ORM and at the same time complain that the code seems hacky. You should put a trace on the database and have a look at the SQL code it generates if you want to see some ugly code!

Comment: If you're doing this only for the sake of arriving at an AutoMapper generated DTO graph, why don't you have AutoMapper do the projection for you as part of the query using the queryable extensions feature? http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Queryable-Extensions.html

Comment: The non hacky way is to define and use proper navigation properties instead of `GroupJoin`. Any manual join in EF is indicator of improper entity model. In your case, the `ContactRoomRole` entity should have navigation property to `Contact` representing the `CreatedBy` FK.

Comment: @IvanStoev The actual query is more complex and requires group join as I have a subquery I'm joining.  This example is just simplified.

Comment: Then may be provide more realistic example. The rules for eager loading are clear - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52767559/does-the-order-of-includes-when-filtering-have-an-impact-on-performance/52768226#52768226. What are you using in your current sample is called tracking and navigation property fixup during the materialization of a query returning entities in memory.

Comment: Normally, projecting an entity's collection along with the entity itself in an anonymous type will wire up the entity's nav property appropriately, so I'm not sure what you're doing that prevents it from happening and I agree with @IvanStoev, the actual code in use is required.  Did you disable tracking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about collections that are marked as loaded, or not.

The line

```
foundRooms.ToList();
```

(or `foundRooms.Load()`)

loads all `Room`s and their `ContactRoomRoles` collections into the context. Since the `Include` statement is used, these collections are marked as loaded by EF. You can check that by looking at

```
context.Entry(Rooms.Local.First()).Collection(r => r.ContactRoomRoles).IsLoaded
```

which should return `true`.

If you omit the line `foundRooms.ToList();`, each time a `Room.ContactRoomRoles` collection is accessed, EF will notice it's not marked as loaded yet and will lazy-load it. After that, the collection is marked as loaded, but it took an extra query.

A collection is only marked as loaded when it is -

- `Include`-ed
- loaded by lazy loading
- loaded by the `Load()` statement, as in

  ```
  context.Entry(Rooms.Local.First()).Collection(r => r.ContactRoomRoles).Load();
  ```

Not when it is part of a projection into another property (like the part `ContactRoomRoles = rm.ContactRoomRole` in your query).

However, after the statement `var roomsData = foundRooms (...).ToList()` all `Room.ContactRoomRoles` are *populated*, because the query did load them into the context, and EF's always executes the *relationship fixup* process, which auto-populates navigation properties.

So, to summarize, after your query you have `roomsData` containing room objects with `ContactRoomRoles` collections that are *populated* but not marked as *loaded*.

Knowing this, it's apparent now that the only thing to do is: prevent lazy loading to occur.

The best way to achieve that is to prevent EF from creating entity objects that are capable of lazy loading, aka *proxies*. You do that by adding the line

```
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

just below the `using` statement.

Now you'll notice that the line

```
var numberOfRoles1 = roomsData.ElementAt(1).Room.ContactRoomRoles.Count();
```

doesn't trigger an extra query, but does return the correct count.

Comment: You say "Knowing this, it's apparent now that the only thing to do is: prevent lazy loading to occur." - however, can't I just use the `.Load()` statement to make EF load the `ContactRoomRoles` collections?  Why do I also need to prevent lazy loading?

Comment: You'd have to `Load()` all collections for each `room` individually.

Comment: This is the correct answer. @Jez, take a look at [Applying filters when explicitly loading related entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data#applying-filters-when-explicitly-loading-related-entities) documentation section. Ignore the filter part: *When using the Query method it is usually best to turn off lazy loading for the navigation property. This is because otherwise the entire collection may get loaded automatically by the lazy loading mechanism either before or after the filtered query has been executed.*

Answer (score 5):

This is not a hack. This is an abstraction leak. We should be ready to meet abstraction leaks using ORM tools (and any other internal DSL).

After `ToList()` you not only execute actual sql call (and load data into memory) but also cross to other Linq flavor - "Linq for objects". After this all your calls of `Count()` doesn't generate sql just because you start working with in memory collections (not with **expression trees** those  are hidden by `IQueryable` - the return type of `GroupBy` statement, but with `List` collection - return type of ToList).

Without `ToList()` you stay with "Linq for sql" and EF will translate each call of `Count()` on IQuerybale to sql; Three Conut() call = three underlined Sql statements.

There are no way to avoid this, otherwise then to calculate all `count(*)` values on server side in one complex query. If you will try to write such query with Linq (constructing `expression tree`) -  you will meet abstraction leak again. ORM tool is designed to map objects to "RDBS entities" staying with CRUD (Create Read Update Delete) operations - if statement become more complex - you will be not able to foresee generated sql (and all runtime exceptions like 'can't generate sql for such linq'). So do not use linq for complex 'report like' queries (in some cases you could - it depends on your re-usage requirements and testing possibilities). Use old good SQL and call it through ADO or EF ADO "sql extensions" like EF Core `FromSql`:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser {0}", user)
    .ToList();
```

Update: it is a good recommendation also to avoid using lazy loading and manual entities loading if you are not working on reusable EF tools. They are in some sense opposite to linq queries - expression trees. They were important (if not only one) option to achieve referenced entities loading on "old" platforms where were no "expression trees" in language but in .NET/EF where full queries can be written "declarative way" as expression trees without execution (but with postponed interpretation) there should be very strong reason to return back to "manual" loading.

Comment: `List<T>` can be converted to `IQueryable` as well by `.AsQueryable()` extension method. The matter is one should understand which implementation (EF query provider or a list wrapper) of `IQueryable` is used in each LINQ call. Also calls over EF `IQueryable` like `.ToList()`, which actually execute SQL, are called materialization in docs.

Comment: Isn't CRUD (Create Read Update Delete)?

Answer (score 1):

This is called an [Abstraction Leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3883006/meaning-of-leaky-abstraction) and it means your abstraction exposes some implementation details.

This is happening when you call the `.ToList()` and you switch (I don't like the word cross) between *[Linq to sql](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/linq/)* and *[Linq to objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/linq-to-objects)*.

I'd recommend you to read [The Law of Leaky Abstractions](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2002/11/11/the-law-of-leaky-abstractions/) to get the grasp better, as it is quite complicated to explain on one foot.

The main idea behind it is, that everything will work as planned but slower then usual when you attempt to provide a complete abstraction of an underlying unreliable layer, but sometimes, the layer leaks through the abstraction and you feel the things that the abstraction can’t quite protect you from.

---

**Edit to clarify:**

calling `ToList()` forces linq-to-entities to evaluate and return the results as a list.

Meaning that, for example from the answer above:

```
var blogs = context.Blogs
    .FromSql("EXECUTE dbo.GetMostPopularBlogsForUser {0}", user)
    .ToList();
```

Will be evaluation to the corresponding model of the context - blogs model.

So in other words, it is being lazily executed at the moment that you call `ToList()`.

Prior to the `ToList()` call, C# does NO SQL calls. So actually, it is NOT an in-memory operation.

So yes,  it is putting that data into memory as part of the context and reads it in the same context.

Comment: This is a good start to an answer, but I'd like more detail on precisely *why* EF is doing this so I can better understand what's going on.  When I call `.ToList()` is it putting that data into memory as part of the context or something?  Does it then read that data later on in the same context?  It seems to me that if it does this they would surely implement a proper mechanism to achieve this behaviour.

Comment: Edited with explanation :)