# Does the order of Include()s when filtering have an impact on performance?

Tags: linq-to-sql, entity-framework-6

This works fine, and I assume it loads all the entities with all the `Foo` and `Bar` children, then filters the results based on `Foo`'s value:

```
var baz = "sillystring";
context.Entities
       .Include(e => e.Foo)
       .Include(e => e.Bar)
       .Where(e.Foo == baz)
       .Select(e.Bar)
       .ToList();
```

So if that's the case, is this a helpful optimization where the filtering is done first and then `Bar` children are included only for a subset of entities?

```
var baz = "sillystring";
context.Entities
       .Include(e => e.Foo)
       .Where(e.Foo == baz)
       .Include(e => e.Bar) // moved to after the filter
       .Select(e.Bar)
       .ToList();
```

... also, is EF clever enough to know that when I use `.Select(e.Bar)` that `Bar` must be included?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The truth is that it really doesn't matter in this case because both `Includes` are ignored. You could remove them and the query will produce exactly the same SQL and result.

This is because `Include`s are in effect only when applied to the query result root entity (if any). Which means they are ignored for projection (`Select`) queries into anonymous / DTO / ViewModel etc. types. Only queries returning directly entity types are considered, and as I said before, if the `Include`s  start from that entity type.

Many people misunderstand the purpose of the `Include`s. They are not needed at all for correctly functioning of the queries that use navigation properties for filtering, ordering, grouping, selecting etc. All their purpose is to [Load Related Entities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data).

In your sample, the only valid includes would be the navigation properties of the `Bar`, and they must be inserted **after** `Select(e => e.Bar)`. Their order is unimportant, as well as the LINQ operators between `Select` and `Include` as sooon as they don't change the query result type.